# Entity Framework - Store parent reference on child relationship (one -> many)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a setup like this:

```
[Table("tablename...")]
public class Branch
{
    public Branch()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

[Table("tablename...")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentBranch")]
    public int? ParentBranchId { get; set; } // Is this possible?
    public Branch ParentBranch { get; set; } // ???
}
```

Is it possible for the User to know what parent branch it belongs to?  The code above does not populate the ParentBranch.

Entity Framework version 5.0
.NET 4.0
c#

Comment: What do you mean by `The code above is not working` ? Are you getting any errors ?

Answer (score 2):

Try making navigation properties virtual,

```
[Table("tablename...")]
public class Branch
{
    public Branch()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

[Table("tablename...")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentBranch")]
    public int? ParentBranchId { get; set; } // Is this possible?
    public virtual Branch ParentBranch { get; set; } // ???
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix it unfortunately

Comment: +1 I was running into the same issue, and making the reference to the parent object virtual fixed it.